# What is the physical importance of current density?

Tags: electric-current

Why we have used the term current density, Is there any physical significance of it or does it affect anything apart from the drift velocity in equations only. Does it have a major significance like charge density in gauss's theorem.

Comment: Ampere's and Ohm's laws, for example.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably most often used in Ampere's Law in Maxwell's Equations:

$$\nabla \times \mathbf{B} = \mu_0 \mathbf{J} + \mu_0 \epsilon_0 \frac{\partial \mathbf{E}}{\partial t}$$

Or, when you start using four-vectors, it's what couples to the electromagnetic field:

$$\partial_{\nu} F^{\mu \nu}=\mu _0 J^{\mu}$$